# StarUML statechart transition line overlapping

Tags: line, transition, statechart, staruml

I'm trying draw statechart in StarUML, found that the transition line overlapping. I want some transition line separated like this:

```
  ------ 
 ( stop )
  ------ 
   | ^ 
 t | | p
   v |
  ------
 ( play )
  ------
```

but always got the transition line overlapping to one double arrow:

```
  ------
 ( stop )
  ------
    ^
   t|p
    v
  ------
 ( play )
  ------
```

Please tell me where I do wrong or what should I do, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can click on one line, hold it, and then drag. You will see that it is actually draggable. Then you can do a CTRL-L with it for final touches.

Answer (score 0):

To get the your desired effect for statechart transitions, and even other things like class diagram associations, perform the following steps:

1. Add your transition
2. Select the transition line by left-clicking on it
3. Change its line style to "Rectilinear"
4. Mouse over one of the square handles at either end of the transition, hold down click, and move it in the desired direction